# Owl Carousel, why page is postback on navigation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, content-srch-slider

I am using owl carousel on a page for slider autoplay as well as for next and previous slides. Everything is working fine as expected. but the thing is whenever I am hitting next or prev button, the page is doing post back and loading everything again.

**Is there any way to stop that post back?**

```
    $(document).ready(function () { 
      var owl = $('.owl-carousel'); 
      owl.owlCarousel({ 
      Items: 1, 
      Autoplay: true, 
      AutoplayTimeout: 5000, 
      AutoplayHoverPause: true, 
      Loop: true, 
      Nav: true, 
    }); 
   });
```

Here, I am using Autoplay as well as navigation. For that, i am using owl.carousel.js and owl.autoplay.js.

I am using this for a **SharePoint Visual Web Part**.

Answer (score 0):

I checked my owl javascript and i notice my "autoplay" is lowercase. JS is case sensitive. All your options seem to be starting with uppercase, i am surprised it works at all. See my code.

```
    $('#owl-example').owlCarousel({
                 items:1,
                 loop:true,
                 margin:0,
                 nav:false,
                 navText:[
              "<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>",
              "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"
              ],
              dots:true,
              dotsEach:true,
              autoplay:true

         })
```

Comment: Which version of owl you are using?